# Scoping problem when replacing json with local data in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am fetching some json data using d3.json and then calling an update function within the `.then`. When I replace the d3.json with the same declared data structure inline then I get an error 'link.data is not a function' at the line `link = link.data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });`
I have tried passing link and node into `update()` but that doesn't work.

I think it is some sort of scoping problem.

```
var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");

d3.json("graph2.json").then( function(json) {
  root = json;
  //Give nodes ids and initialize variables
  for(var i=0; i<root.nodes.length; i++) {
    var node = root.nodes[i];
    node.id = i;
    node.collapsing = 0;
    node.collapsed = false;
  }
  //Give links ids and initialize variables
  for(var i=0; i<root.links.length; i++) {
    var link = root.links[i];
    link.source = root.nodes[link.source];
    link.target = root.nodes[link.target];
    link.id = i;
  }

  update();
});


function update() {
  //Keep only the visible nodes
  var nodes = root.nodes.filter(function(d) {
    return d.collapsing == 0;
  });
  var links = root.links;
  //Keep only the visible links
  links = root.links.filter(function(d) {
    return d.source.collapsing == 0 && d.target.collapsing == 0;
  });

  force
      .nodes(nodes)
  force
      .force("link")
      .links(links)

  // Update the links…
  link = link.data(links, function(d) { return d.id; }); 
  .......
```

The code that fails (with the data structure and d3.json commented out) is below.

```
json = {
  "nodes": [
    {"x": 469, "y": 410},
    {"x": 493, "y": 364},
    {"x": 442, "y": 365},
    {"x": 467, "y": 314},
  ],
  "links": [
    {"source":  0, "target":  1},
    {"source":  1, "target":  2},
    {"source":  2, "target":  0},
    {"source":  1, "target":  3},
    {"source":  3, "target":  2},
  ]
}

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");

//d3.json("graph2.json").then( function(json) {
  root = json;
  //Give nodes ids and initialize variables
  for(var i=0; i<root.nodes.length; i++) {
    var node = root.nodes[i];
    node.id = i;
    node.collapsing = 0;
    node.collapsed = false;
  }
  //Give links ids and initialize variables
  for(var i=0; i<root.links.length; i++) {
    var link = root.links[i];
    link.source = root.nodes[link.source];
    link.target = root.nodes[link.target];
    link.id = i;
  }

  update();
//});


function update() {
  //Keep only the visible nodes
  var nodes = root.nodes.filter(function(d) {
    return d.collapsing == 0;
  });
  var links = root.links;
  //Keep only the visible links
  links = root.links.filter(function(d) {
    return d.source.collapsing == 0 && d.target.collapsing == 0;
  });

  force
      .nodes(nodes)
  force
      .force("link")
      .links(links)

  // Update the links…
  link = link.data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });
.....
```

Comment: In Javascript `var` variables have no block scope, but they do have function scope. In your second code you're overwriting `var link`, while in your first code, due to the scope of the function inside the `then` method, you have 2 different `var link` (and `node` as well). The solution is trivial, just chose another name.

Comment: Great thanks Gerardo. I renamed the variables in the for loops. I took the first code from elsewhere so no sure why it used the same name for the SelectAll and the variables in the for loops.